# VS Code python debugger only works one time.

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The debugger in VS Code in only working one time (either using debugging or start without debugging) and after that it won't start at all. I then have to restart VS Code and it works. I only have this issue since updating to v1.18.1.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same thing. Even with a completely fresh install. This is quite a show stopper, any pointers appreciated.

In the statusbar i can see python being running still and i have not managed to stop it besides restarting vsc.

Comment: I have installed VS code 64bit (available since July) and I don't have this problem anymore. I use python 64bit as well. Before the last update of VS code I was using python 64bit with VS code 32bit. I don't know if this is even related to the problem but it fixed it for me.

Comment: Hm, using both 64bit versions right from the start here. Still seeing this issue.